# Why does UDF throw NotSerializableException in streaming queries?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.4.3 for one structured streaming application (readStream from Event Hub Azure / writeStream to CosmosDB). There are some transformation steps for the data and one step is to make a lookup into CosmosDB for some validation and adding some more fields.

```
//messagesF13 contains PersonHashCode,....
...
val messagesF14 = messagesF13.withColumn("LookupData", getHData($"PersonHashCode"))
//messagesF14.printSchema()
messagesF14.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").option("truncate", false).start().awaitTermination()
```

The code for getHData is copied below:

```
case class PersonHolder( id: String, 
                    Person_uid: String,
                    Person_seq: Integer)

val getHData= udf ( (hash256: String) => {
         val queryStmt = s""" SELECT * 
                                FROM c
                                WHERE c.Person_uid ='$hash256'"""
        val readConfig = Config(Map("Endpoint" -> "https://abc-cosmos.documents.azure.com:443/",
                                   "Masterkey" -> "ABCABC==",
                                   "Database" -> "person-data",
                                   "preferredRegions" -> "East US;",
                                   "Collection" -> "tmp-persons", 
                                  "query_custom" -> queryStmt,  
                                  "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0"))

          val coll = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
          coll.createOrReplaceTempView("c")

          val q3 = queryStmt + " AND c.Person_seq = 0"
          val df3 = spark.sql(q3)

          if (df3.head(1).isEmpty){
              null //None
          }
          else {
              val y = df31.select($"id",$"Person_uid",$"Person_seq")
              val y1 = y.as[PersonHolder].collectAsList
              y1.get(0)
          }
  }
)
```

It does not work, the (well known) error is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder
```

What are the possible workarounds/solutions for avoiding the error? 
Thank you in advance for some links/GitHub code/docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It does not work

And it won't. Sorry.

User-defined functions (UDFs) run on executors where there is no `spark.sqlContext`. Both `spark` and `sqlContext` are uninitialized on executors.

> one step is to make a lookup into CosmosDB for some validation and adding some more fields.

That's a classic join, esp. with this code in the `getHData` udf:

```
val coll = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
```

You should simply do the following:

```
val coll = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
val messagesF14 = messagesF13.join(coll).where(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Jacek. I will go with the [join].

Comment: @dag My pleasure. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. I'm sure it will :)